# XHR и получение результата C#

Tags: c#, xhr, веб-скрейпинг

Здравствуйте. Есть сайт, где содержимое страницы подгружается с использованием ajax (по-моему). Если открывать его в webbrowser и пытаться читать содержимое с использованием xpath, то удается получить только первую страницу, все остальные в исходном коде не отображаются.
На одном форуме вычитал, что в таких случаях стоит использовать xhr-запросы. Но только вот как их правильно использовать - понятия не имею. Может кто-нибудь привести пример, с которого будет понятно как с этим работать? Средства неважны, лишь бы только это был язык C#. Также прикрепляю скрин с содержимым xhr интересующего сайта (хотя, я не уверен, что выделил все правильно, мб чет упустил, поправьте, если так).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]